# Did you know there is a chat room for physics?

Tags: discussion

Sorry for such pseudoquestion, but check it out:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/physics

Comment: Nope; thanks for notifying :)

Comment: Oh, that's quite nice. Eventually, we should be getting our own chat sub-site, but this is a good temporary solution.

Comment: @Noldrin Not any more; only SOFU sites have dedicated chat subpages.

Comment: Oh dear, that must have changed very recently. Oh well.

Comment: It was deleted but now it works again.